# Push Notification on published app only works on non-development device

Tags: iphone, push, token

I have an app in the store and push works for anyone having bought the app, no problem there.
But it does not work on the two phones we used for development.
How do we solve this?
tunebot for iphone

Answer (score 1):

With regards to push notifications, you have two different servers with two different certificates for the notifications. One of those is a test/development server, which has one set of permissions. The other is a production server with a different set. If you go to the iOS Provisioning Portal and click on App IDs, you'll see that the second column has two rows, one for development PN and one for production. Start here and make sure your development ones are configured properly.